# Can a stake account be re-delegated?

Tags: account, stake

On blockchain explorer you’ll see that a stake account may have an “activated” epoch, and a “deactivated” epoch.

Does that mean that a single stake account can only be “used” once? I.E. there can only be one delegate instruction and one deactivate stake instruction per stake account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stake account may be reused as many times as desired, but can only be delegated to one place at a time. This means you can do:

- delegate
- wait to activate
- deactivate
- wait to deactivate
- delegate somewhere else